# Heroku: Run a Rails application with a Python script on the same instance

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, bash, heroku

I have a Python script in the `/app/bin` directory of my Rails app that contains a `requirements.txt` file that includes all of the dependencies it relies on.

How do I get it to run on the same Heroku instance that my Rails app currently runs on (my Rails app call the python script occasionally).

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Put the `requirements.txt` file in the `/` dir. Didn't install any python dependencies
2. Tried running `heroku run bash` and then running `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Got the message `pip command not found`.
3. Tried installing pip through the bash interface using `sudo python get-pip.py` after `curl`ing the script as suggested on the [pip installation site](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html). Didn't work -- not surprisingly, they don't support `sudo` commands on the instance.

I know Heroku is supposed to support `pip` out of the box, but it doesn't seem to do anything with the `requirements.txt` file once it's detected a `Ruby` app.

Comment: Consider using the https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi to run both the python and the ruby application on the same instance using their respective buildpacks.

Comment: @SampritiPanda thanks, same answer I got from the Heroku support team. Want to break it out into an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Heroku Buildpack Multi](http://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to run both the python and the ruby application on the same instance using their respective buildpacks.

Answer (score -1):

1. keep requirements.txt file in project folder. In my case project name is stock09. so requirements.txt file in side of stock09
2. heroku login
3. heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
4. heroku buildpacks.set heroku/python
5. heroku buildpacks
6. git add .
7. git commit -m " "
8. git push heroku master

now it work